# Focus to HTML hidden component, what happens?

Tags: javascript, html

In practice, what happens when we target a js click event over a hidden HTML component?

Will the focus move to the HTML tree's first component?

Like this:

```js
function setCalculoInterprete() {
  document.getElementById("formAJIntranet:calcularValorFinalSolicitacao").click();
}
```

```html
<input jsfc="cl:commandButton"
  id="calcularValorFinalSolicitacao"
  value="Calcular valor final"
  actionListener="#{visao.controlador.calcularValorSolicitacaoInterprete}"
  alt="Calcular valor final da solicitação"
  style="font-size: 12px; margin-left: 10px; display: none;"
  title="Calcular valor final da solicitação"
  onkeypress=" " onfocus=" " onblur=" " />
```

Comment: You can't "focus" on something that isn't rendered...

Comment: How is that lookup by ID even working?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot focus on a hidden element.

If you set the input style to:

- `display: none` or
- `visibility: hidden`

After you click the button <kbd>Grant Focus</kbd>, while *hidden*, and start typing, the focus will revert back to the last focused element (the button you clicked). Instead of actually hiding it, just move it off-screen.

### Demo

To demonstrate this concept, first click <kbd>Grant Focus</kbd> (while the input is still "hiding"). Now, start typing something. Once you are done typing, click <kbd>Toggle Input</kbd>, and the input will appear with the text you were typing, because it had focus.

```js
const txtHidden = document.querySelector('#hidden-text')
const btnGrant = document.querySelector('.btn-grant')
const btnToggle = document.querySelector('.btn-toggle')

const handleGrantFocus = (e) => {
  txtHidden.focus()
}

const handleToggle = (e) => {
  txtHidden.classList.toggle('hidden')
}

btnGrant.addEventListener('click', handleGrantFocus)
btnToggle.addEventListener('click', handleToggle)
```

```css
form {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1000px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-grant">Grant Focus</button>
<button class="btn-toggle">Toggle Input</button>
<form autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" class="hidden" id="hidden-text" />
</form>
```